# ClearCase continually stops the deliver operation

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm extremely new to ClearCase and am trying to do a deliver operation on a project I'm working on. The problem is, I continually see the following happen during the delivery:

[image: Eror Popup]

Obviously this isn't too helpful of an error message... I use the default deliver for this, and I'd say this happens ever 10-20 minutes, when I hit OK it closes the whole thing and I have to resume the operation, only for this to happen again. I've been trying to complete it for a few days now, and I'm starting to suspect that it may not be doing anything in between these errors.

Has anyone else ever seen this error before? Anyone know how to fix it? If you need any other info let me know -- as I said, very new to ClearCase.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are confronted with a "bizarre" GUI error, fall back to command-line: at least there you might see a more explicit error message.

In the destination view you were using, try a:

```
cleartool deliver -resume -reset -stream aStream@\apvob -gmerge
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am required to use a VM where the command line is disabled in order to do this delivery.... Trust me, I hate GUI when command lines are available, I've tried every trick in the book to get a command line onto the VM they provided me with.

Comment: What is the OS for that VM? And what is the version of ClearCase used?

Comment: VM is running Windows 7 Enterprise, not sure on the Clearcase version, it all got installed automatically, I have very little control over this system if you couldn't tell haha